# Help choosing between reload or subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i want to know the best way to re import or re execute a module, because i have a web server with just one Apache session for all my domains and applications, and i if i need to make some changes on one application restart the server will affect the others, so looking for the best way to recall a module. If i choose subprocess i will need to print the response but i don' t know is that most secure way of communication. Please tell me in your experience which is the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your setup or the problem. Restarting Apache is so fast people hardly notice, and I'm not sure why the single apache session would mean you can't restart your python servers separately.

Comment: @S.Lott yes i am using mod_wsgi, but that's not the problem

Comment: @hidura: When you touch the `wsgi` script, the application is reloaded.  Doesn't that solve your problem completely?

Comment: @Lennart Regebro, is fast but if i have 3 applications(a,b,c) running on the same Apache session and i restart the session, because i make some changes on the application 'c', 'a' and 'b' will be affected and that's definitely is not the plan.

Comment: Because Apache will be close for all the requests in the moment of the restart, probably the restore will take 5 mls but if there any request coming in that time the server will not respond. That's a problem because is not very professional thing. I prefer avoid that problem and give some semi-independence to the application from Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading a module is rarely a good idea in a production environment; it's a mechanism intended for debugging. When you reload a module, the module's contents (classes, function, data) get replaced, but existing references to these items from other modules are not affected. This is particularly important for classes: existing objects in memory still refer to the old class, whereas objects generated after the reload refer to the new class.

There is another alternative you might want to consider: load Python code from a file and exec it. Less overhead than a complete subprocess, and less tightly coupled to the rest of a program than a module. In principle the same caveats apply to re-exec-ing as to reloading a module, but you are much less tempted to have references to exec'd code because it's more work.

Comment: Thanks that's mean i going for subprocess, because i don't have to much time for make a long code. Thanks!!!!